# Redirect and open Edit Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, popup

I am stuck in a problem where I have a link which has an `anchor` tag and href is set to open some feedback. The anchor tag deals as a single `Note` and I need to open a popup to delete this `Note`. I am binding this anchor tag with in a `span` and applying onclick to open `Edit Popup`.

Here is my HTML

```html
<span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial;float:left; cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:OpenMoveFeedback('4909','2838','0');">
   <a href="http://localhost:16185/SurveyDesigner/FeedbackReport.aspx?RequestId=7f2679e8-d131-47d8-9074-318516c7b95b&amp;$$$$=4909" 
       target="_Blank" 
       style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; color: #0431B4; font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial;">
     View Anonymous Feedback 
   </a> 
   (Form: ff5).
</span>
```

As you can see there is a function `OpenMoveFeedback` which will open a popup and the anchor tag has some redirect to itself.

Now the point is when user click on `(Form: ff5)` it will open that popup (no issue here), but when user click on `View Anonymous Feedback` it will open a new tab in browser window + it will also trigger the popup. I don't want to open that popup is this case.

Please suggest me what I have to update here. I am building the data from json ajax. There is no data in client side code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `currentTarget` in the `OpenMoveFeedback()` function. If the event is not generated by the `<span>`, then simply `return` from the function. This will prevent the function from executing (and opening a popup) when you click on the link and not on the `<span>`.

eg:

```
function OpenMoveFeedback(event){
  if(event.currentTarget.tagName == 'a'){
      //event is generated by <a>, do nothing 
      return;
  }
  /*
    rest of your function code.
  */
}
```

Comment: I need to open the provided feedback in new window when user click on "View Anonymous Feedback" but when user click on rest part i.e. the span text "(Form: ff5)" it should trigger the edit popup.

Comment: Its always giving SPAN for event.currentTarget.tagName

Answer (score 0):

it's because your "View Anonymous Feed" is also inside the span with some javascript codes.

just do something like.

```
<a href="http://localhost:16185/SurveyDesigner/FeedbackReport.aspx?RequestId=7f2679e8-d131-47d8-9074-318516c7b95b&amp;$$$$=4909" target="_Blank" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; color: #0431B4;font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial;">View Anonymous Feedback </a> <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial;float:left; cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:OpenMoveFeedback('4909','2838','0');">(Form: ff5).</span>
```

Comment: The html within a span tag sabed in db so I cannot update it. But I need to make it editable so I bind it with in a span.